# Crystal Reports - entire groups duplicated

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

I have a report showing purchases and sales by client. My top group is client. Beneath that I have a purchase (invoice #) group and sale (sale #) group. These can have multiple items on them. What I'm finding is the following:

Client 1
Purchase 1
-purchased item 1
-purchased item 2
Sale 1
-sold item 1
-sold item 2
-sold item 3
Purchase 2
-purchased item 1
-purchased item 2
**Sale 1

-sold item 1

-sold item 2

-sold item 3**

Sale 1 group is duplicated, presumably because there are two purchase groups and only one sale group for this client. How do I avoid this duplication? Ideally, I'd like to show purchase 1, purchase 2, sale 1, rather than purchase, sale, purchase, sale, but if I can just get rid of the duplicate group I'd be happy.

Comment: How are the joins between tables in your database defined in database expert?  This sounds like you may have a cartesian product resulting from a weak join between tables.  More often than not, this is caused by using a Full Join between tables that should be a Left Inner Join.

Comment: So for purposes of this report, customers have purchases but may or may not have sales. We want them to show up anyway,  and just NULL values for the sale info if there are no sales, we used left outer join for the sales. If there isn't a way to circumvent this in Crystal we can try re-working it.